# pointing rails app to read only db for all DB read operations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a rails 4.2.8 app which has a ton of SQL reads hitting the Main DB (which is MySQL 5.7 running on AWS RDS Aurora engine), while the read-only replica (which is constantly replicating data from the Main DB) is sitting idle.

What is the right way to configure the rails code to use the read-only DB, while continuing to use the Main DB for all Write operations (e.g. INSERTs, UPDATEs, DELETEs) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at https://github.com/thiagopradi/octopus -- it looks like it's designed to solve your problem.

> Octopus is a better way to do Database Sharding in ActiveRecord. Sharding allows multiple databases in the same rails application. While there are several projects that implement Sharding (e.g. DbCharmer, DataFabric, MultiDb), each project has its own limitations. The main goal of octopus project is to provide a better way of doing Database Sharding.